# CreateCursor using ICONINFO

Tags: c++, winapi

Is it possible to create a cursor from `ICONINFO iconinfo.hbmMask` and  `iconinfo.hbmColor` using `CreateCursor`

Passing `iconinfo.hbmMask`as a AND and `iconinfo.hbmColor` as XOR to `CreateCursor` throwing exception.

```cpp
HICON Create_Cursor(CURSORINFO CursorInfo)
{   
    ICONINFO iconinfo;
    HICON hIcon = NULL;

    bool bIconInfo = GetIconInfo(CursorInfo.hCursor,&iconinfo);

    if(!bIconInfo)
    {
        // GetIconInfo failed.
    }

    hIcon = CreateCursor(   NULL,
                            iconinfo.xHotspot,
                            iconinfo.yHotspot,
                            32,
                            32,
                            iconinfo.hbmMask,
                            iconinfo.hbmColor   );

    if(hIcon == NULL)
    {
        // CreateCursor failed.
    }
    return hIcon;
}
```

`CreateCursor` is failed after passing `ICONINFO`, How can I get `HCURSOR` using `CreateCursor` API... No proper examples in internet about 'CreateCursor'
this article will helps if someone answer.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

### I strongly suggest reading:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/menurc/about-cursors

### To your code:

The `ICONINFO`s masks and color data contain HBITMAPS 
but the `CreateCursor` API function requires plain bit data.

Also `CreateCursor´ API seems not to support colors at all.

Please have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/menurc/using-cursors

The `ICONINFO` documentation says that the hbmMask does contain the `AND` and `XOR` part:

> hbmMask
>
> Type: HBITMAP
>
> The icon bitmask bitmap. If this structure defines a black and white
>   icon, this bitmask is formatted so that the upper half is the icon AND
>   bitmask and the lower half is the icon XOR bitmask. Under this
>   condition, the height should be an even multiple of two. If this
>   structure defines a color icon, this mask only defines the AND bitmask
>   of the icon.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-_iconinfo)

### to the general problem:

the documentation also says:

> Applications should implement custom cursors as resources and use
>   LoadCursor, LoadCursorFromFile, or LoadImage rather than create the
>   cursor at run time. Using cursor resources avoids device dependence,
>   simplifies localization, and enables applications to share cursor
>   designs.

And the help for the `SetCursor` Function suggests:

> hCursor
>
> Type: HCURSOR
>
> A handle to the cursor. The cursor must have been created by the
>   CreateCursor function or loaded by the LoadCursor or LoadImage
>   function. If this parameter is NULL, the cursor is removed from the
>   screen.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-setcursor)

So it seems that you just can pass the handle of a loaded image to this function.

The documentation of `CreateIconIdirect` sugggests that `HCURSOR`s and `HICON`s are interchangable:

> Creates an icon or cursor from an ICONINFO structure.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-createiconindirect)

Comment: "So it seems that you just can pass the handle of a loaded image to this function." I suspect you were faked out by the function name "LoadImage". That function loads bitmaps, cursors, and icons. To get a cursor, you have to pass `IMAGE_CURSOR` to LoadImage.